# No Debug Information in Perspective in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, perspective

I'm working on a project and stumbled upon an error, that I couldn't solve with help of this great forum.

I have the problem, that I set breakpoints, started `Debug Mode Run` and in `LogCat` view 
I see the program suspends at the right position (made information lines).
Now when I switch to `Debug Perspective` I see no information in the `Variables View`,
or in the `Debug View`.
I'm used to see the thread and the postion in my program + the Variables and the values of it. I'm also not able to use the Step functions (<kbd>F5</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd>).

In `DDMS Perspective` I see my emulator connected and can see the threads and that my App is flagged for debug.

I use Eclipse JUNO, ADT 23.0.2, emulator uses an API lvl 10 (2.3.3).
I can't remember what I did but now there comes afterwards debugger connected and waiting to settle with success.

In Command console it says Debugger is attempting to connect at port 8614.

I tried on a different PC with new Eclipse, the same problem.
I added the Debug Flag in my Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
```

Hope someone can help me.

Greets 
Harald

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit embarrising, but i solved my own problem.

I simply had to Fix my Project.

Right-click on the Project -> `Android Tools` -> `Fix Project Properties`

So this is for all that run in the same Problem.